# Setting a generic ArrayList to zeros

Tags: java, generics

I have an ArrayList. I would like to set each element of it to 0. Right now I have:

```
ArrayList <T extends Number> arr = new ArrayList();

for(int i = 0; i < some_other_array.size(); i++)
{
    arr.add(0)
}
```

The compiler complains that

```
error: no suitable method found for set(int,int)
            arr.add(0);
               ^
    method ArrayList.set(int,T) is not applicable
      (actual argument int cannot be converted to T by method invocation conversion)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Number
```

Comment: `arr.size()` is zero, so this will be a no-op in any event.

Comment: Oops, I'm actually using a different ArrayList to control the for loop. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: Your new version (once it compiles) will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException...

Comment: Ok thaks for pointing that out. I should've been using arr.add(0). Edited again.

Comment: You should use `arr.add(0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be done. The method signature for  is

```
 public T ArrayList<T>.set(int index, T element)
```

Even though the constraint on `T` is that it `extends Number`, it does not mean that it can be *constructed from a number*.

Consider, for example,

```
class FortyTwo extends Number {
      public byteValue() { return 42; }
      public intValue()  { return 42; }
      // etc
}
```

What would you expect the initialization routine to do to an `ArrayList<FortyTwo>` ?

Comment: Ok, yeah now that I think about it, I understand what you're saying. Guess I'm going to have to find a different way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your list declaration to

```
ArrayList<Number> arr = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

`arr` will be capable of holding anything extending [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) (which is what you want, I assume).

Now, when you do

```
arr.set(i, 0)
```

that `0` will be autoboxed to an `Integer`. (See for yourself, add `0` and print `arr.get(0) instanceof Integer`.)

If you wanted to add `double`s or `long`s for instance, you could use the literals `0d` and `0L`, respectively.

Comment: Would that work if the ArrayList was instantiated as ArrayList<Float>, for example?

Comment: But note that `ArrayList<E extends Number>` is quite different from `ArrayList<Number>`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your case: `arr.set(i, Integer.valueof(0));`

Or you can reuse this handy standard API: `Collections.fill(arr, Integer.valueof(0));`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the declaration of your ArrayList to

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

The Integer class supports auto-boxing, while the Number class does not. Also, the `add()` method may be more applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to set the value to 0, it will be automaticaly zero as ArrayList object will be instantiated. So the code will be useless as the size will be zero at the time so loop will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you're a little confused about how `ArrayList` actually works. When you create an `ArrayList`, it's always empty. Even if you specify a size:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(20);
```

That `20` just means "initial capacity", not "starting number of elements". As a result, `set` will never work  because there are simply no elements. Even if you fix your compiler issue like this:

```
arr.set(i, Integer.valueOf(0));
```

Or like this:

```
ArrayList<Number> arr = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

It's not even going to do anything because `arr.size()` is zero, so the `for` loop won't even run.

The key here is that `ArrayList` **is not** an actual array. It wraps an array, and will expand its inner array when it has too many elements. In other words, I can't do this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(20);
arr.get(0); // Throws an out of bounds exception
```

Now, that being said, if you *want* to start with 20 zeroes in your `ArrayList`, you can use the `add` method in your loop and `i < 20` instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    arr.add(Integer.valueOf(0));
}
```

This will add 20 zeroes to `arr`. Your code, even after fixing the error, will not.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this (to the best of my knowledge, you cannot add primitive types to ArrayList):

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < someNumber; i++)
{
   arr.add(0);
}
```

Remember that when size is 0 because it does not have any default values and the capacity is what you should be looking at (You can set the capacity in the constructor.)

Comment: Adding generics to an ArrayList has worked up to this point, so I don't think the issue is that.

Comment: Then I am not sure, sorry :/. I would think that the for loop would not even be called because the arr arraylist has no elements and thus no size and I also would think set wouldn't do anything because there are no elements to set, but maybe I have confused some stuff.